# How to deploy multi-container on Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to deploy this app, which consists of a Flask API and a MongoDB database, which is mounted to a volume.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to upload the Dockerrun.aws.json file to Beanstalk, but I keep getting this error:

`[Instance: i-0f9dd8d8d30059929] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].`

This is my Dockerrun.aws.json file:

```
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "nielshoogeveen1990/image-classifier:latest",
            "links": [
                "db"
            ],
            "name": "api",
            "memory": 128,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 5000,
                    "hostPort": 5000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "mongo:3.6.4",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql/data",
                    "sourceVolume": "Db-Data"
                }
            ],
            "name": "db",
            "memory": 128
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "db-data"
            },
            "name": "Db-Data"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected more logs? Any other error messages?

Comment: No unfortunately not. But (I know it's a vague question) is my Dockerrun.aws.json correct?

Comment: The file is missing opening `{`, but this is probably due to copy and paste to SO.